# how to use a relative endoint address?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jax-ws

Using Spring boot configuration i have the exception

```
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /CustomerService
```

How to put a relative (to the deployed webapp) url?

```
@Bean 
public EndpointImpl endpoint(ICustomerService customerService) {        
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(cxfBus, new WCustomerService(customerService) );
        endpoint.publish("/CustomerService"); 
        return endpoint; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to pass a valid URL as a string to publish as you can see that in the below function. It is a snippet of EndpointImpl.java. Hope this helps.

```
public void More ...publish(String address) {
127        canPublish();
128        URL url;
129        try {
130            url = new URL(address);
131        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
132            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot create URL for this address " + address);
133        }
```

Comment: it looks like it need a different url with a different port, so that's way it can't be relative the webapp adress

Comment: It needs to be a complete URL with protocol, domain etc.